# Unable to launch Steam on Nvidia 495 driver, 5.4 kernel, Linux Mint 20.3

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, nvidia, troubleshooting, steam

After a few weeks of not having time for games, today I am unable to launch Steam.

I do not remember some bigger change in the system = Linux Mint 20 than upgrading my Mint today from version 20.2 to 20.3.

---

Here is `dmesg` snippet:

```
$ \dmesg --human --color=auto --ctime
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] kernel BUG at drivers/gpu/drm/drm_gem.c:154!
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] CPU: 6 PID: 5273 Comm: steam Tainted: P           OE     5.4.0-92-generic #103-Ubuntu
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 7577/0J8HMF, BIOS 1.15.0 10/08/2021
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] RIP: 0010:drm_gem_private_object_init+0xa2/0xb0 [drm]
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] Code: 00 31 c0 c1 e9 03 f3 48 ab 48 c7 43 18 00 00 00 00 48 c7 83 c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5b 41 5c 5d c3 4c 89 a3 f0 00 00 00 eb b2 <0f> 0b 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] RSP: 0018:ffffa720444a7d08 EFLAGS: 00010206
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] RAX: ffff906ae37ca568 RBX: ffff906ae37ca558 RCX: 0000000000000200
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] RDX: 0000000000000200 RSI: ffff906ae37ca400 RDI: ffff906b2c174000
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] RBP: ffffa720444a7d30 R08: ffff906ae29f7908 R09: ffff906ae29f7908
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] R10: ffff906b12cf4008 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff906ae37ca400
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] R13: 0000000000000200 R14: ffff906b2c174000 R15: ffff906ae239f800
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff906b30380000(0063) knlGS:00000000f7821740
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] CS:  0010 DS: 002b ES: 002b CR0: 0000000080050033
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] CR2: 00000000587a3000 CR3: 0000000823210004 CR4: 00000000003606e0
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] Call Trace:
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022]  ? nv_drm_gem_object_init+0x54/0x60 [nvidia_drm]
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022]  nv_drm_gem_import_nvkms_memory_ioctl+0xa7/0x100 [nvidia_drm]
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022]  ? nv_drm_dumb_create+0x1b0/0x1b0 [nvidia_drm]
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022]  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xae/0xf0 [drm]
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022]  ? _nv038665rm+0xac/0x1a0 [nvidia]
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022]  drm_ioctl+0x24a/0x3f0 [drm]
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022]  ? nv_drm_dumb_create+0x1b0/0x1b0 [nvidia_drm]
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022]  ? __check_object_size+0x13f/0x150
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022]  ? nvidia_ioctl+0x39b/0x8d0 [nvidia]
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022]  drm_compat_ioctl+0xcb/0xe0 [drm]
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022]  __ia32_compat_sys_ioctl+0x194/0x220
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022]  do_fast_syscall_32+0x9d/0x260
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022]  entry_SYSENTER_compat+0x7f/0x91
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] RIP: 0023:0xf7efdb49
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] Code: c4 8b 04 24 c3 8b 14 24 c3 8b 1c 24 c3 8b 34 24 c3 8b 3c 24 c3 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 51 52 55 89 e5 0f 34 cd 80 <5d> 5a 59 c3 90 90 90 90 8d b4 26 00 00 00 00 8d b4 26 00 00 00 00
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] RSP: 002b:00000000ffa2ea18 EFLAGS: 00000282 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000036
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000011 RCX: 00000000c0206441
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] RDX: 00000000ffa2ead4 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 000000005877af90
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] RBP: 00000000f696eba4 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm xt_multiport xt_owner ip6_tables cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep xt_limit ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_conntrack xt_tcpudp xt_length xt_comment xt_u32 iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_mark xt_cgroup iptable_mangle iptable_raw bpfilter binfmt_misc nvidia_uvm(OE) nls_iso8859_1 joydev mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel dell_laptop kvm nvidia(POE) dell_smm_hwmon dell_wmi snd_hda_codec_hdmi iwlmvm mac80211 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio libarc4 dell_smbios dcdbas rapl snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi uvcvideo btusb videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops btrtl videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_seq btintel videobuf2_common bluetooth videodev intel_cstate snd_seq_device mc cdc_acm ecdh_generic ecc snd_timer mxm_wmi
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022]  hid_multitouch iwlwifi input_leds serio_raw dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof intel_wmi_thunderbolt cfg80211 snd processor_thermal_device soundcore intel_rapl_common ucsi_acpi mei_me typec_ucsi mei intel_soc_dts_iosf intel_pch_thermal typec int3403_thermal intel_hid int3402_thermal sparse_keymap int3400_thermal int340x_thermal_zone acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs xor zstd_compress raid6_pq libcrc32c usbhid hid_generic i915 i2c_algo_bit ahci crct10dif_pclmul drm_kms_helper crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt intel_lpss_pci i2c_hid fb_sys_fops crypto_simd intel_lpss nvme cryptd r8169 idma64 glue_helper psmouse drm nvme_core i2c_i801 libahci realtek virt_dma hid wmi video
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] ---[ end trace 34d885d0821661da ]---
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] RIP: 0010:drm_gem_private_object_init+0xa2/0xb0 [drm]
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] Code: 00 31 c0 c1 e9 03 f3 48 ab 48 c7 43 18 00 00 00 00 48 c7 83 c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5b 41 5c 5d c3 4c 89 a3 f0 00 00 00 eb b2 <0f> 0b 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] RSP: 0018:ffffa720444a7d08 EFLAGS: 00010206
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] RAX: ffff906ae37ca568 RBX: ffff906ae37ca558 RCX: 0000000000000200
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] RDX: 0000000000000200 RSI: ffff906ae37ca400 RDI: ffff906b2c174000
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] RBP: ffffa720444a7d30 R08: ffff906ae29f7908 R09: ffff906ae29f7908
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] R10: ffff906b12cf4008 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff906ae37ca400
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] R13: 0000000000000200 R14: ffff906b2c174000 R15: ffff906ae239f800
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff906b30380000(0063) knlGS:00000000f7821740
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] CS:  0010 DS: 002b ES: 002b CR0: 0000000080050033
[Fri Jan  7 19:41:33 2022] CR2: 00000000587a3000 CR3: 0000000823210004 CR4: 00000000003606e0
```

---

If I run `steam` from terminal, I get:

```
$ steam
steam.sh[7775]: Running Steam on linuxmint 20.3 64-bit
steam.sh[7775]: STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
setup.sh[7910]: Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
steam.sh[7775]: Steam client's requirements are satisfied
$
```

I did not change my kernel, but I remember updating it via regular updates. The only *red* line is:

> ```
> kernel BUG at drivers/gpu/drm/drm_gem.c:154!
> ```

---

I am now running Nvidia drivers of 495.46 version.

---

PS: On Windows 10 the Steam and games work.

Comment: I have the same problem, Ubuntu 22.04, kernel 5.15.0-39-generic and Nvidia driver 510.73.05 not sure the reason but start happening just after update, I can still open Steam but only trough the console and previously ending all the steam processes running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue got resolved by reverting to Nvidia driver version 470.86.

So, maybe the 495 driver branch is not game-ready yet. In any case, I am leaving the question here for other readers.

Comment: I'm not convinced it's just 495. If this checks out, it's the latest patch that's bad. I've had 495 for a while now without problems, but after the latest update, it seems to have gone bad

Comment: Same thing with 515 drivers...